# Problem with importing module for opening some files

Tags: python

Doing some practice in Python. I created a module with function to count words in text files.

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/home/yuriy/Dropbox/Prog/Python/learning/em book/ch 10/text_files/')

def count_words(file):
     
    try:
        with open(file) as file_object:
            content = file_object.read()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File cannot be found")
    except ModuleNotFoundError:
        print("Module cannot be found")
    else:
        words = content.split()
        num_words = len(words)
        result = f"{file} has {num_words} ~words in it"
        print(result)
```

But when I import this and try to use it with one or multiple files, it gives me back an FileNotFoundError

```
import sys

sys.path.append('/home/yuriy/Dropbox/Prog/Python/learning/em book/ch 10/modules/')

import def_count_words

files = ['blank.txt','learning_python.txt']

for file in files:
    res = def_count_words.count_words(file)
    print(res)
```

Here is the screenshot of directory i am working in:

[image]

The .py file I am working in is ch 10_test.py

I am clearly missing something or doing something wrong and I can't get my head around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sys.path is a list of directories that python is using to look up for modules. It will not use these directories to look for files in general. You can use `os.path.join` to create a full path for your files:

```py
base_dir = '/home/yuriy/Dropbox/Prog/Python/learning/em book/ch 10/text_files/'

myfile = open(os.path.join(base_dir, file))
```